# How to make the content of this modal vertically centered on mobile screen

Tags: html, css

The modal is full screen and on the large screens image (modal content) is full screen however when you test it in a mobile screens image with other content is in the top of the modal and the bottom part of the screen is completely empty. Here are the 2 classes:

```
.slide-modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top:10px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000000;
  }

  .slide-modal-content {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
  }
```

I can't show complete code since it's too large and based on Angular. Also, it's without bootstrap. Please don't provide any solution that is based on bootstrap.
I assume I should add a separate case for devices with max-width of 600px for example but what should be changed in the existing classes to move the content of the modal vertically in the center?

Comment: That's little bit unclear, try to provide more code and details.

Comment: Have you tried bumping the z-index number up. It's not a fix at all but it will show you if the mobile css has a higher z-index and thus covering over the modal.

Answer (score 0):

`transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` will help you to align the content in the center of the screen but you will need to add `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;`

```css
body {
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/any);
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide-modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.slide-modal-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* to center the content */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 450px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  max-height: 60vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Title title
</h1>

<p>
  Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
</p>
<p>
  Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
</p>
<p>
  Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
</p>
<p>
  Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
</p>
<p>
  Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
</p>
<p>
  Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
</p>
<p>
  Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
</p>
<p>
  Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
</p>

<div class="slide-modal">
  <div class="slide-modal-content">
    model content
    <p>
      Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
    </p>
    <p>
      Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
    </p>
    <p>
      Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
    </p>
    <p>
      Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
    </p>
    <p>
      Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
    </p>
    <p>
      Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
    </p>
    <p>
      Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
    </p>
    <p>
      Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Nunc nec neque. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Cras id dui.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image was inside the modal. Thanks for replying I will test it and let you know.

Comment: In this position:absolute; will causes problems in responsive mode so use position:relative.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use below `css` and it will work fine in **responsive mode** also.

```
.slide-modal {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top:10px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

.slide-modal-content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying I will test it and let you know.